# Cannot find pid of daemonized python thread using ps aux

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-multithreading

I am running the following program on a rhel 7 machine:

(python3.9)

```
import threading
import time

def countdown(count):
  print(f'Thread alive? {thread.is_alive()}')
  print("Counting down...")
  while count > 0:
    print(f'{count} left')
    count -= 1
    time.sleep(2)
  print("We made it!")

thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(500,))
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()


while True:
  time.sleep(2)
  print(f'Thread still alive? {thread.is_alive()}')
  print(f'The trhead id: {thread.native_id}')
print("End of program.")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaDkv.png)

As shown in the picture below, the native thread id of the daemonized subthread is 28435, however, when looking up this thread using ps aux, i cannot find it, nor can i only kill the subthread without killing the main thread also (using kill -9 28435)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxbHX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc301.png)

Where could i see using bash if the subthread is running? And how can i only kill the sub processes from the command line without killing the main thread?

I have tried different kill levels but all seem to stop the main thread, and i cannot find the pid using the top command.

Comment: Instead of `ps aux`, use `ps -eLf`. Also take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1071